# Getting how the view was called with HttpRedirect in the next view

Tags: python, django, redirect

I have two views in django: one which loads the page, and one which saves a form. I've separated the two so I can stay on the same page without a page refresh causing a resubmit.

The create view which saves the form redirects back to the view that loads the page with `HttpResponseRedirect`.

Is it possible, in the load page view, to get if the view was called by the create view with the redirect?

So:

```
def holiday(request, value=None, year=None, month=None):
    if request.method == "GET":
        # set some variables for the view
        year = something
        month = something_else
    else:
        # get if the view was executed from a redirect
        # set year and month to be something2 and something_else2

    # calendar

    holidayform = HolidayForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    context = {
        "holidayform": holidayform,
        "calendar": mark_safe(cal),
        "year": year,
        "month": month,
    }
    return render(request, "tande/calendar.html", context)
```

Then the view that saves the form:

```
def create_holiday(request):
    overlapping_dates = False
    if request.method == "POST":

        #save the form... or don't

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("tande:holiday"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpResponseRedirect` will literally redirect the user. Basically, it is as if the user had typed in the URL in his browser and pressed enter. Which means some information from the past request won't be available.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-subclasses

You can pass a flag through a GET parameter. It'd do the trick:

```
HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("tande:holiday") + '?redirect=True')
```

And then in your `form_view` read the GET parameters:

```
if request.GET.get('redirect', None):
    do_something()
```

You just gotta think what is going to happen if the user intentionally add that GET parameter to the URL. He can fake the result. If your intention is displaying a message then it won't be a problem.